# Various thumbnail sizes for Wordpress/jquery masonry gallery

Tags: thumbnails

can someone help me to create a thumbnail gallery in Wordpress using jquery masonry which looks similar to [this](http://erikjohanssonphoto.com/work/imagecats/personal)?

I am not sure what the best approach is. Especially regarding the different thumbnail sizes. When and how to assign them?
I get the part where I set a few different thumbnail sizes, but how do I decide which size to load? Since that page always loads the same way it doesn't seem to be randomized.
Can the masonry script take care of that itself?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I usually set up my image sizes then within each post I have a metabox with a radio button group to select what image size I want to use within my masonry grid. When displaying my posts I check for the meta value and then grab the appropriate image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a grid setup, with your guttering, and setup JQMasonry to appyl itself to everything in that grid.

Then add image sizes for the sizes of tiles you want using add_image_size in `functions.php`. You will need to regenerate any existing image thumbnails after this has been done.

Then finally display your posts. Use div elements sized to the right tile size, containing the featured image of the associate tile size.

How will you pick the size? Well aside from picking ti manually in some post meta, you can use the trusty random PHP functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

So if you've got 3 tile sizes ( like the page you linked to ), use `rand` to generate a number between 1 and 3, then have an array with your tile sizes and pick one:

```
$tile_sizes = array('small','medium','big');
foreach post
    $random_size = rand(0,2);
    $chosen_size = $tile_size[$random_size];
```

Also if using `WP_Query` or `get_posts`You may also want to set a random order when you make your query to further randomise things

Comment: Thanks. So it is safe to assume that in the linked example, the thumbnailsizes are not randomized but manually set for each picture? Reload the page, everything stays the same.

Comment: Yes, though there's no reason they couldn't be

Comment: Finally got around to check back. Thanks for the input, I ended up adding a custom field to the attachment edit screen where I can set one of several thumbnail sizes for each image individually.