# Add image size array to a portfolio thumbnail in combination with Masonry Jquery Plugin

Tags: post-thumbnails

```
add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 250, 9999 ); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
```

I am using the above code within my functions.php file, to generate various thumbnail sizes for my masonry portfolio theme.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Can the above take an array of images within this to randomise the images that is displayed within the grid?

Thanks
Kirsty

Comment: Are you trying to show the masonry layout on your homepage using posts?

Comment: Hi sprclldr. I have this as a template, and ive set it as a custom template, but ive set a post thumbnail size, but i want to vary it? So like a variation dependant on the overall original picture size maybe? So if its less that 300px wide it would be 250 wide, and if it is less than 600 it would be 500 wide... if that makes sense

Comment: http://erikjohanssonphoto.com/work/imagecats/commissioned/ ... Bit like this? Theres like a variation of images

Comment: they have done this with wordpress so im not sure how :S

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are having specifically. Have you contacted the support for your theme?

Comment: Hi sprclldr. Its not a problem. I want to know if i can pass an array on the post thumbnail to support multiple thumbnail sizes like the theme link above

Comment: Okay, and you're trying to randomize which images appear? Or the just sizes they appear at?

Comment: Hi sprclldr i want to randomise the sizes. Bit like the link i sent you above, they have a variety of image sizes. I didnt know if u had to pass an array in the post thumbnail?

Answer (score 1):

[the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) only retrieves the specified thumbnail size for the current post. You'll need to write a conditional function or use a [custom query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to randomize the posts shown or thumbnail sizes from your theme's loop.

If you are familiar with where your loop starts, then:

```
$tile_sizes = array('small','medium','category-thumb');

LOOP STARTS

$random_size = rand(0,2);
$chosen_size = $tile_sizes[$random_size];
the_post_thumbnail($chosen_size);

LOOP ENDS
```

Comment: ok i will have to look at that :) as im very new to wordpress. Ive tried to look at tutorials for this and not alot on it :)

Comment: Start here if you are starting Masonry from scratch: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/using-jquery-masonry-for-pinterest-like-posting/

Comment: hi sprclldr i have that, however that is restrictive to one size (220px wide), where i want to vary the sizes pulling through :S

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67050/various-thumbnail-sizes-for-wordpress-jquery-masonry-gallery

Comment: i have found this, however this function or query above im not sure where to put this, is this in the wp_query section?